# Executing libimobiledevice commands over wifi

Tags: ios, itunes, libimobiledevice

I am trying to recreate the trustjacking attack presented by Symantec at RSA 2018 but I have been unable to execute libimobiledevice commands remotely through iTunes wifi sync.

When I have a physical USB connection between my ios device and the computer all the commands work perfectly but when I enable itunes wifi sync and disconnect the cable I can no longer contact to the device.

However, when I run `idevice_id -l` over wifi it displays the uuid of my ios device but any other commands just display errors such as `ERROR: Could not connect to device` or `No device found, is it plugged in?`.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its turns out that my version of libimobiledevice was corrupt as well as the dependencies. I fixed this by completely reinstalling libimobiledevice and its dependencies as well as removing all previous data stored by libimobiledevice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I had to uninstall the libmobiledevice completely and re-install it again. I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/717#issuecomment-430622355) here for complete instructions and hence I am sharing the commands here as well for convenience for the future developers.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
sudo rm /var/db/lockdown/*
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
```

If you do not have brew installed in your machine, please follow the instruction from [this website](https://brew.sh/).